# php array remove n amount of items based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array, there are 4 values = 3, how can i delete just two of them?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 1 
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3 
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 2 
)
```

I already tried [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). is there any way to achieve this ?

so the array looks like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3 
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2 
    [8] => 2 
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 2 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make two calls to `unset`, using `array_search`:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6);
print_r($array);
unset($array[array_search(3, $array)]);
unset($array[array_search(3, $array)]);
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
)
```

But this assumes that you are OK with the behavior of `array_search`, which would return the *first* index which matches the value 3.  If you had some other order of removal in mind, then state it, and the code might have to be changed.

Comment: is it posible to leave intact the first coincidence? it is not a requirement, just out of couriosity

Comment: @HéctorPérezSilva I don't think `array_search` can be used in this case.  You would have to iterate the array using some sort of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a loop and skip the first 2 times you encounter a 3. Then for the next matches, you could use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). Then you might use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the keys:

```
$items = [
    1,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,2
];

$found  = 0;
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($item === 3) {
        if ($found < 2) {
            $found++;
            continue;
        }
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
}
print_r(array_values($items));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 2
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/398bf)